# Angr considers REP instruction as the end of a basic block

Tags: python, disassembly, angr

I'm developing a python script for Angr that has to find all the basic blocks present in each function in a binary. I have noticed that Angr splits the basic blocks when he finds a `REP` instruction, I'm wondering if I can tell Angr to not split basic blocks when encounters `REP` instructions with the API or if I have to do it manually.

This is a snippet of my code:

```
p = angr.Project(sys.argv[1], auto_load_libs=False, main_opts={'base_addr': 0} )
cfg = p.analyses.CFGFast()
cfg.normalize()

for func_node in cfg.functions.values():
    for block in func_node.blocks:
        c = block.capstone
        for i in c.insns:
            * operations *
```

This is an example of a basic block that ends with a `REP` instruction:

[image]

Thank you in advance.